# RabbitMQ create custom user roles

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

i have tried creating a user with different policies to achieve my requirement, i want to create a user which have privilege to create users but not to delete so far i have failed. Please help

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to accomplish (beyond what has been asked here)?

Answer (score 1):

> i want to create a user which have privilege to create users but not to delete

This is not supported by RabbitMQ.